# What is the Herman-Skillman method?

Tags: solid-state-physics, pseudopotentials

In the paper [Norm-Conserving Pseudopotentials (1979)](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.43.1494), they refer to the authors' book for the all-electron(AE) calculation:

`we first carry out an ab initio self-consistent full-core atom calculation via a Herman-Skillman-like program`.

**What is the Herman-Skillman method?**

Edit:
I want to use these potentials for a plane-wave calculation on a 2D graphene layer.

Answer (score 3):

In Herman and Skillman method - numerical methods were performed for self-consistent field calculations based on simplified model of Slater’s version on Hartree-Fock equations for one electron wave function. Where it was suggested to use an average exchange potential which could be approximated by results taken from theory of free electron gas.  The model provides description of electronic structure of free atoms and ions. Calculations were performed using programs written in FORTRAN, such as Hartree Fock Slater self-consistent atomic field program, Relativistic and spin orbit corrections programs etc. 
You can refer to the book **Atomic Structure Calculations Prentice-Hall, Englewood Cliffs, NJ (1963)**

 Note- I am not a good explainer. Please accept my apologies, but you can refer to the book. Also, I have read somewhere about Herman-Skillman mesh, example like - An energy-minimizing mesh for the Schrödinger equation, (https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-9991(89)90124-1)

Comment: What differentiate a Herman and Skillman calculation from a HF calculation in the case of an infinite periodic material?

Comment: @mle that looks like a new question, which would require a new post.